# How to make variables in a war receive a parameter from TomCat?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, netbeans, war

i have a Web Service Project made in maven and generated a .war from it. I've been told to configure the project so that the generated war can take a variable (the port) from TomCat, since this war is gonna be deployed in various machines. The problem is that i have no idea of how to configure the project (i think i can add a property variable) to receive this variable in each TomCat machine.

I have to configure the port variable in a project-conf.xml file.

Comment: See [Tomcat documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/context.html#Context_Parameters).

Comment: You can use:
        ${cathome}/conf/catalina.properties 
    and map those properties to your 
        applicationContext.xml

Comment: I've create a temporal solution to my problem and it was to define variables catalina.port and catalina.log.path in the file catalina.bath on the TomCat Server, by this way when i create the war it builds up with the variables set on the server. I call the port and path of TomCat from my properties by placing ${catalina.port} & ${catalina.log.path} variables Respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I've create a temporal solution to my problem and it was to define variables catalina.port and catalina.log.path in the file catalina.bath on the TomCat Server, by this way when i create the war it builds up with the variables set on the server. I call the port and path of TomCat from my properties by placing ${catalina.port} & ${catalina.log.path} variables Respectively.